# Max local split-screen players for Crash Team Racing Nitro Fueled on Xbox-one

Tags: crash-team-racing-nitro-fueled

How many players can play local split-screen? I'm not interested in anything to do with online play, I need to know how many people can play on the SAME local system at a time. Almost all game-play I've seen is for 2 player local and I can't seem to find a definitive answer anywhere if 4 is possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The game supports up to 4 players locally.  This can be seen on its [product page](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/p/crash-team-racing-nitro-fueled/bww032506dpf?activetab=pivot:overviewtab) on the Microsoft Store.

Another [source](https://www.androidcentral.com/crash-team-racing-nitro-fueled-everything-you-need-know) states:

> If online multiplayer isn't your thing, you'll be happy to know that it still offers local 4-player split screen.

Comment: And I confirm it by having tested it.